# Example of using Cassandra data model for Apache Mahout

Tags: cassandra, mahout

I am looking for example of using "CassandraDataModel" for Mahout. Also what tables are needed and how to import data into those tables from CSV files

Answer (score 0):

Posting this, If others face same issue with Windows version of Cassandra 3.9.0 (DataStax Distribuition).

Following are the tables that need to be created through CQL: 
CREATE TABLE "users" ("userID" bigint , "itemID" bigint,value float,PRIMARY KEY ("userID","itemID") ) WITH COMPACT STORAGE;

CREATE TABLE "items" ("itemID" bigint , "userID" bigint,value float,PRIMARY KEY ("itemID","userID")) WITH COMPACT STORAGE;

CREATE TABLE  "userIDs" ("ID" bigint , "userID" bigint, PRIMARY KEY ("ID","userID")) WITH COMPACT STORAGE;

CREATE TABLE  "itemIDs" ("ID" bigint , "itemID" bigint, PRIMARY KEY ("ID","itemID")) WITH COMPACT STORAGE;

Following is the format of command for importing  data from CSV files to these 4 tables.

copy users from 'C:\Recommender_mv\RecommenderApp\data\movies.csv';